# NavigationView click event

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using the android navigation drawer navigation menu from the Android Studio template. How do I navigate to the different activity based on the id.

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.admin_panel_navigation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

[image]
I tried the below set of codes, but it doesn't perform the click operation.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

       case R.id.nav_maths: {
      //do somthing
            break;
        }  
    }
    //close navigation drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I know I am missing something, but I am not able to find the solution. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Tie destinations to menu items section](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer), Navigation uses the IDs you add to your menu xml, matching them to destinations in your navigation graph xml file.

So if you had a menu item such as

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_maths"
    android:icon="@drawable/maths"
    android:title="@string/maths" />
```

and wanted it to start a different activity, you could add an `<activity>` destination to your navigation graph:

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/nav_maths"
    android:name="com.your.package.MathsActivity" />
```

And because they have the same ID, your activity would be started when you click that item in your menu.

Note that Navigation focuses on having just a single activity, so an activity destination should be considered an exit point from your graph - your second activity would have its own navigation graph, etc. that is completely separate from the first one.

Comment: I am using the fragments. Since the first fragment is loaded and others are not loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, nor how that relates to starting an activity when you click a menu item in the NavigationView?

Comment: It's just the template I have used from Android studio, and it works for the first Item. whenever I click on another item it doesn't open the fragment.

Comment: The same thing applies to `<fragment>` destinations - does the id in your menu xml match the id of the `<fragment>` destination in your navigation graph xml file? If you're having a different issue from this question (which was about starting an activity when clicking on a menu item), perhaps you should ask that as a separate question?